# Can anybody explain "financials have been mostly in negative territory" for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Against the backdrop of ultralow rates and a go-slow approach by the Fed, 
**financials have been mostly in negative territory for the year**, and of the six 
names mentioned in Goldman’s report, only Zions has outperformed the S&P 500 in 2016.

source:

Comment: It means that  financial stocks prices  (bank, insurance etc.) are generally   lower than their closing prices on the last trading day of 2015. Take Citigroup for  instance, its closing price for 2015 was around $52 while as of yesterday's close it was arond $46,50.

Comment: The "negative territory" is e metaphor for the negative gap between the two prices. In a similar fashion you would speak about "positive territory"  for the prices  which are higher than 2015 closing.,

Answer (score 1):

*Territory* is a fancy word for *area*, especially when there are multiple forces "fighting" or in contest for a single area, and then *territory* can be used to describe an area owned by something or someone.

Financial reports are influenced by things that can be considered "forces" and the writer/speaker is abstracting "positive" and "negative" as forces that fight over territory, and the "negative side" is currently "winning."